# Почему я могу обратиться к div с классом block через селектор .block.block?

Tags: css

Вот такой вопрос) 
Почему текст внутри блока красный? 
Что так можно обращаться? Какая тут логика?

```css
.block.block {
  color: red;
}

div[class=block] {
  color: blue;
}

div {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Текст
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что селектор `.block.block` считается более узким/специфическим, чем остальные.

```css
div.block.block {
  color: green;
}

.block.block {
  color: red;
}

div[class=block] {
  color: blue;
}

div {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Текст
</div>
```

Comment: А какая логика? Я обращаюсь к блоку у которого класс block и класс block. Так странно)

Comment: @Григорий Да. Вот такой искусственный способ заставить браузер использовать переопределенный стиль.